# Password issue while installing RVM on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install Ruby on AWS EC2 instance. 
For this I installed RVM, it worked fine and for Ruby, I gave:

```
[root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ec2-user]# rvm install ruby 2.2.3

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: redhat/7/x86_64/ruby-2.2.3.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for redhat.
Unable to locate SystemId file. Is this system registered?
Unable to locate SystemId file. Is this system registered?
Enabling optional repository
Username: ec2-user
Password:
```

> An error has occurred:  See
>   /var/log/up2date for more information Requirements installation failed
>   with status: 1.

I know that when I run all this installations I have to use **sudo -s** such that there is no requirement of password, but still it is asking. 
What might be wrong? Please help me.

Comment: have you tried running `rvm install ruby` as the `ec2-user` instead of `root`?

Comment: Yes, there also the same problem.

Comment: can you update your question with some actual error logs?